# lag function with condition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark i want to count true columns which comes before false
this is my table:

condition is

> if d_difference > 900 then its consider as false otherwise true

```
id          date1               date2            d_difference    status    
534     18/03/15 11:50:30  18/03/15 11:50:45         15          true
534     18/03/15 11:50:50  18/03/15 11:50:59         09          true
534     18/03/15 12:00:30  18/03/15 12:35:45         1815        false
534     18/03/15 12:00:50  18/03/15 12:36:45         2165        false
534     18/03/15 12:37:30  18/03/15 12:37:45         15          true
534     18/03/15 12:38:00  18/03/15 12:38:10         10          true
534     18/03/15 12:42:30  18/03/15 12:50:45         495         true
534     18/03/15 12:50:50  18/03/15 01:15:45         1505        false
534     18/03/15 12:50:30  18/03/15 12:50:55         20          true


val v2 = v1.withColumn("status",when($"d_difference" > 900,false).otherwise(true))

v2.withcolumn("lag_data",when ($"staus" === false ,lag("status",1).over(w)).otherwise(null)).show()
```

I am using spark lag function to calculate previous true condition which comes before false but its failed...

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is just idea I could think of. I dont have IDE to test ant run it.
Just trying to help by the way could think of.

Lets say you have a column status with true and false values. We have to count number of trues before first false.
The one way I can think of with RDD is.

Get the rdd containg status. lets day rddOfStatus.

```
rddOfStats.zipWithIndex().filter(condition).first
```

1. zipWithIndex will index eache status like 
   "true",0
   "true",1
   "false",2
2. filter this and get the first element (tple) which is

"false",2

3. from this tuple we can extract the value and get the count.

**OR same thing can be done with Dataframe or Spark SQl.**

1. Add a column with rownum to assign numbers to each row,
2. then filter all true and keep only false
3. then get the minimum row_number

Answer (score 0):

> i can use 2 time window function to calculate all false

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date1","date2")
 val w1 = Window.partitionBy("id","status").orderBy("date1","date2")
 val r1 = ($"status" !== lag($"status", 1).over(w) && $"status").cast("bigint")
 v2.withColumn("new_session",r1)
 val t1 = v2.withColumn("session",sum(r1).over(w1)).show()
```

> i get total count of false value which comes before true .

Answer (score 0):

> If you want cumulative sum of `True` before `False` then you can refer
>   below code:

```
    scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    scala> val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("id")
    scala> val w1 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("rn")

 //Input data frame
    scala> df.show()
    +---+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------+
    | id|            date1|            date2|d_difference|status|
    +---+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------+
    |534|18/03/15 11:50:30|18/03/15 11:50:45|          15|  true|
    |534|18/03/15 11:50:50|18/03/15 11:50:59|          09| false|
    |534|18/03/15 12:00:30|18/03/15 12:35:45|        1815| false|
    |534|18/03/15 12:00:50|18/03/15 12:36:45|        2165| false|
    |534|18/03/15 12:37:30|18/03/15 12:37:45|          15|  true|
    |534|18/03/15 12:38:00|18/03/15 12:38:10|          10| false|
    |534|18/03/15 12:42:30|18/03/15 12:50:45|         495|  true|
    |534|18/03/15 12:50:50|18/03/15 01:15:45|        1505| false|
    |534|18/03/15 12:50:30|18/03/15 12:50:55|          20|  true|
    +---+-----------------+-----------------+------------+------+

    scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("rn", row_number over(w))
    scala> val df2 = df1.filter(col("status") === "false").withColumn("prv_rn",  lag("rn" ,1,0) over (w))

    scala> val df3 = df2.withColumn("sum", (col("rn") - col("prv_rn") - 1)).withColumn("true_count", sum(col("sum")) over(w1)).select("id","date1","date2","status","true_count")

  //Join final output
    scala> df.join(df3, Seq("id","date1","date2","status"),"left").show()
    +---+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------+----------+
    | id|            date1|            date2|status|d_difference|true_count|
    +---+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------+----------+
    |534|18/03/15 11:50:30|18/03/15 11:50:45|  true|          15|      null|
    |534|18/03/15 11:50:50|18/03/15 11:50:59| false|          09|         1|
    |534|18/03/15 12:00:30|18/03/15 12:35:45| false|        1815|         1|
    |534|18/03/15 12:00:50|18/03/15 12:36:45| false|        2165|         1|
    |534|18/03/15 12:37:30|18/03/15 12:37:45|  true|          15|      null|
    |534|18/03/15 12:38:00|18/03/15 12:38:10| false|          10|         2|
    |534|18/03/15 12:42:30|18/03/15 12:50:45|  true|         495|      null|
    |534|18/03/15 12:50:50|18/03/15 01:15:45| false|        1505|         4|
    |534|18/03/15 12:50:30|18/03/15 12:50:55|  true|          20|      null|
    +---+-----------------+-----------------+------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you and i appreciate your efforts....but i want count not a sum..but ur ans is not right if u want sum of rows so basically u need to sum only true rows that comes before false....and u can do that with single window function u dont need to do join also..@ Nikk

Comment: what shoud be expected output dataset? can you provide it.